# AEM 6.1: How to get the warning icon in a cq:dialog

Tags: warnings, aem, xtype

AEM 6.1: How to get the warning icon in a `cq:dialog`. Is it some xtype that would help? If it were a pop up then,
`CQ.Ext.Msg.show({ "icon":CQ.Ext.MessageBox.WARNIN, })` helps
but for  "`cq:Dialog`", How should one **

Display the warning icon

With the warning message in a `cq:dialog`.

```
"jcr:primaryType": "cq:Dialog",
        "height": 240,
        "title":CQ.I18n.getMessage("Activate Later"),
        "id": CQ.Util.createId("cq-activate-later-dialog"),
        "params": {
            "_charset_":"utf-8"
        },
        "items": {
            "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Panel",
            "items": {
                "jcr:primaryType": "cq:WidgetCollection",
                **"warnMsg": {
                    "xtype": "displayfield",
                    "html":CQ.I18n.getMessage("my warning message here."),
                    "hideLabel":true,
                    "hidden":flagHidden,
                    "name":"warnMsg",
                    },**
                "absTime": {
                    "xtype": "datetime",
                    "fieldLabel":CQ.I18n.getMessage("Activation Date"),
                    "name":"absTime",
                    "allowBlank": false
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: I tried below but there is a blank space instead of icon
"warnMsg": { "xtype": "dialogfieldset", "layout":"anchor", "hideLabel":true,                   
                    "iconCls":CQ.Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
                    "title":"warning",
                    "name":"warnMsg", "defaults": {
               "anchor": "-200" // leave room for error icon
            },
                    "items":[{
                        "xtype":"label","html": CQ.I18n.getMessage(msg),
                        "iconCls":CQ.Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
                    }]
                },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code removes the text from wrapping around the icon displayed

```
 "warnMsg": {
                        "xtype": "dialogfieldset",                            
                        "hideLabel":true,
                        "hidden":flagHidden, 
                         "html": "<div><img style='float:left; padding-right:10px' src='/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/window/icon-warning.gif'></div><div style='font-size:12px; margin-left: 40px;'> Your text here</div>",                    
                        "title":"Warning",
                        "name":"warnMsg"
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display field and specify the required output in the `html` property as shown below.

```
"warnMsg": {
    "html": "<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/window/icon-warning.gif'><div style='vertical-align:middle; display:inline;'>Warning</div>",
    "xtype": "displayfield",
    "hideLabel": true
}
```

A similar SO question has been [answered here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979569/not-able-to-show-image-on-dialog-box-in-aem/31995600#31995600).

Comment: Thank you @rakhi4110, I had tried using html img tag and it did work for me but was wondering if it would be an apt way of doing it. Felt there would be a way out using some xtype where we can specify the class name for the icon in a cq : dialog. as we have for MessageBox show method.